# how to set class on table in spesific tr?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I need to set class on table on spesific tr on ajax proses. my html table like below

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-borderless table-hover" id="tablePray">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="width:20%;">Nama / Name</th>
                    <th style="width:45%;">Keterangan / Description</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($prays as $row)
                {
                    ?>
                      <tr id="prayRow<?php echo $row->id;?> ">
                        <td class="user-avatar"> <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/admin/img/avatar.gif" alt="Avatar"><a href="#"><?php echo $row->name;?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->prayNeed;?></td>
                        <td class="text-right">  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item healedList" data-id="<?php echo $row->id;?>" onclick="confirmStatus(<?php echo $row->id;?>)">Healed</a></td>

                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

and my jquery like this :

```
 $('#changeStatusFrm').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $id=$('#idPray').val();
      $token=$('#token').val();

      data = new FormData();
      data.append("idPray",$id);
      data.append("<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>", $token );

      $.ajax({
          data: data,
          type: "POST",
          url: '<?php

              echo base_url('Pray/ChangeStatus');
              ?>'
          ,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(url) {
              var result=url.split('|');

              $('#token').val(result[0]);

              alert('Pray status have been change');
              $("#mod-danger").modal("hide");

              $("#tablePray tr#prayRow"+$id).addClass('table-success');

          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              alert(err.Message);
          }
      });
  });
```

I want to change the spesific tr if row link get click. 
Can anybody help me?? thx

Comment: What error are you getting in above code?

Comment: nothing error showed. but if change from $("#tablePray tr#prayRow"+$id).addClass('table-success'); to $("#tablePray tr).addClass('table-success'); it works. but I don't want that

Answer (score 1):

If you are using datatable then you can use something like this :

```
  $('#tablePray').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { className: "my_class", "targets": [ 0 ] }
  ]
} );
```

reference link :- https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className

Answer (score 0):

Set like this

```
var val = "#prayRow"+$id;

$(val).addClass('table-success');
```

Make sure `#prayRow$id` is already defined in table

FYI: move `alert('Pray status have been change');` to end of the line

Comment: thx for yor help. but I already try that and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

This example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html) demonstrates adding and removing classes on a row from a click event.